# Is $(((\alpha \rightarrow \beta) \rightarrow \gamma) \wedge (\alpha \rightarrow \gamma)) \rightarrow \gamma$ provable in IL?

Tags: logic

I was wondering whether

$(((\alpha \rightarrow \beta) \rightarrow \gamma) \wedge (\alpha \rightarrow \gamma)) \rightarrow \gamma$

is provable in intuitionistic logic. Provided it is, could you please show me a derivation of it? If it is not, could you please show me a Kripke-tree that refutes it?

Comment: This looks like it may be homework, so this is just a very light hint: what if $\beta = \bot$?

Comment: Mmm can't get the hint (but thank you)

Comment: However, I was thinking that the Kripke-tree consisting of a single empty node would falsify the formula, but since I'm not very into Kripe-trees I don't know whether one can take one with a single empty node.

Otherwise, I was also thinking of using the sub-formula principle for normal derivations of IL, in which case it seems to me that such a derivation cannot exist (think of the formula as made of atoms, then the I-part must be one step of $\rightarrow$-intro and up you can't apply any elimination for formulas which be sub-formulas of the conclusion)

Comment: OK. Now, I'll say more about my hint: if you take $\beta = \bot$, your formula becomes $((\lnot \alpha \to \gamma) \land (\alpha \to \gamma)) \to \gamma$ - which is the law of the excluded middle. So the formula is not provable.

Comment: I see that it reminds of EM, but...can you derive EM from it? I mean, $\alpha \vee \neg \alpha$?

Comment: Yes. Just take $\gamma = \alpha \lor \lnot\alpha$.

Comment: yeah I find it :) Last question: would the Kripke-tree I suggested work as a counter model to the sentence?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by an empty node, but whatever it is, a Kripke tree with only a single node cannot falsify any classically valid formula.  Your formula can, however, be falsified by a Kripke tree with just two nodes, say $a$ and $b$, with $b$ accessible from $a$. Take $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ to be true  only at $b$, and take $\beta$ to be false at both nodes.

Comment: You can also establish it as unprovable in IL by just looking at all the subexpressions (it is easier if you convert $(a \land b) \to c$ to $a \to (b \to c)$).  Since propositional IL is normalizable by design, and is easy to see that no proof can be constructed using only the subterms of the intended result, there can't be any proof in IL.

Comment: Yes this with normalisation was a possible solution I thought about, see above. It works with atoms rather simply. Thank you all

Comment: As for the Kripke-tree, I was thinking of one with a single node where no formula is forced. @AndreasBlass would you please explaining me why it doesn't work? And why yours instead works?

Comment: In a one-node Kripke model with all of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ false at the node, you have, at that node, $\alpha\to\beta$ true, therefore $(\alpha\to\beta)\to\gamma$ false, therefore $((\alpha\to\beta)\to\gamma)\land(\alpha\to\gamma)$ false, and therefore $(((\alpha\to\beta)\to\gamma)\land(\alpha\to\gamma))\to\gamma$ true. So you don't get a counterexample.

Comment: Right! Thank you!

So Milne's generalized first introduction rule for implication is false in IL, and that is quite strange to me.